# Symfony2 multiple file upload error

Tags: php, symfony

Hi i am facing an error while doing a multiple upload. A quick nut shell:

1. Single file upload works perfectly allright.
2. Have specified the multiple attribute to the form element.
3. Have specified full_name to the element. But, once the form is submitted, only the last upload(5th file if i am uploading 5 files), gets uploaded.

I am struggling to handle the rest of the files. I am pasting my code below. Could any one help me out please. Thanks in advance.

Form code:

```
    <?php $formalbum = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('albumname', 'text', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-    control','placeholder'=>'Album Name')))
    ->add('albumdescription', 'textarea', array('required'=>FALSE, 'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Album Description')))
    ->add('image','file', array('constraints'=>array(new Assert\Image(array('mimeTypesMessage'=>'Opppp!! That was not an image file'))),"attr" => array("accept" => "image/*","multiple" => "multiple", 'full_name'=>'image[]')))
    ->add('submit','submit', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-success','placeholder'=>'Create Album')))
    ->getForm(); ?>
```

Form handling code:

```
    <?php $formalbum['image']->getData()->move($dir, $profileimage); ?>
```

Comment: Extremely sorry for this unformated code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for formatting my code.